# How to connect two computer on Internet using Sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to send data from PC-01 to PC-B, two computer connected on internet. Is it possible to write socket program in c#? I try to search lot, all most example on local computer or using static ip address.

**Computer 1** -> Internet Service Provider (having IP: 116.203.188.231) -> Broadband Router -> PC-01/PC-02

**Computer 2** -> Internet Service Provider (having IP: 49.202.72.175) -> Broadband Router -> PC-A/PC-B

I try this:

On server:

```
m_socListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
m_socListener.Bind(ipLocal);
m_socListener.Listen(4);
m_socListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
```

On Client:

```
m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(49.202.72.175);
int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt32(8000);
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip.Address, iPortNo);
m_socClient.Connect(ipEnd);
EnableCommands(false);
//watching for data
```

Above code have no problem, but it is not working. When trying to connect it saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I checked firewall and allow the application & port for both system.

IP of connecting computer is: 116.203.188.231 and IP of another computer is 49.202.72.175. The IP 49.202.72.175 is provided by ISP (it is not static ip and also this may share by other user from isp's end) and also more than computer connected to internet through 49.202.72.175 using local lan. So can I connect the computer using socket? Or is there any technology to connect two computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually the port `8000` is blocked by the systems firewall. Try use non-blocking ports or open firewall on both the machines.

Comment: You have to configure port forwarding on your router (on the listening side)

Comment: _"Is it possible to write socket program in c#?"_ - yes. _"Or is there any technology to connect two computer?"_ - yes. But please start small, using two programs on your own computer, and pick up a book about basic networking to learn identify and troubleshoot issues like this. Most definitely port forwarding.

Comment: Given the language you are using, it is highly unlikely you want to use Raw Sockets. Are you doing RTC? Are you using a custom protocol? Are you trying to achieve low latency? If you cannot answer yes to ALL of those, please look at WCF or other IPC frameworks.

Comment: Thanks to all for comments and sorry for late response. @cackharot I tried to others port also and also disabled firewall, I can connect but when sending data saying "an existing connection was forcible closed by remote host".

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski I do not want to forward port.

Comment: @CodeCaster above code working LAN (using 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2), but when trying to connect using internet as per above example it is not working, please can you suggest any book.

Comment: If you don't want to configure port forwarding manually, you'll have to do that with UPnP from your program. One way or another, you'll have to because of how NAT works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can

If you want to send it through socket you can see an example here :

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Communication-through-91a2582b

Also, your firewall is probably blocking this port. You can change the port to 80, which is usualy open, or set an exaption in all firewalls involved

This is nice if you always know the ip of the other computer

Otherwise, I recommand to use a server that will connect between them

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link